# How to delete all files from folder with Databricks dbutils

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, dbutils

Can someone let me know how to use the databricks dbutils to delete all files from a folder. 
I have tried the following but unfortunately, Databricks doesn't support wildcards.

```
dbutils.fs.rm('adl://azurelake.azuredatalakestore.net/landing/stageone/*')
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more information if referring to deleting all files or folder as well

Answer (score 44, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dev-tools/dbutils.html#file-system-utilities), the rm function receives 2 parameters :

rm(**dir**: String, **recurse**: boolean = false): boolean -> Removes a file or directory

Where the second parameter is a boolean flag to set the recursitivity, so you just need to set it to true:

```
dbutils.fs.rm('adl://azurelake.azuredatalakestore.net/landing/stageone/',True)
```

Comment: This deletes the directory as well. How to delete all files *without* deleting the directory?

Comment: @jegordon your answer is wrong the question is to remove the files not the folder itself.

Comment: wrong anser, this removes the folder as well, not only the content of the folder. (in this case the special folder permission are also deleted)

Comment: dbutils.fs.rm("adl://azurelake.azuredatalakestore.net/landing/stageone/", **true**)

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work:

```
val PATH = "adl://azurelake.azuredatalakestore.net/landing/stageone/"
dbutils.fs.ls(PATH)
            .map(_.name)
            .foreach((file: String) => dbutils.fs.rm(PATH + file, true))
```

Answer (score 3):

To sum up all the above answers:

1. to delete the whole folder, use:

   ```
   PATH = "adl://azurelake.azuredatalakestore.net/landing/stageone/"

    dbutils.fs.rm(PATH,True)
   ```

2) to delete all the files and subfolders, except this folder itself, use:

```
   PATH = "adl://azurelake.azuredatalakestore.net/landing/stageone/"
   for i in dbutils.fs.ls(PATH):
        dbutils.fs.rm(i[0],True)
```

I tested by myself, and it works!

Let me know if you have any concern.

--Shizheng

Answer (score 1):

Enhance to [ezraorich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73552458/5172807), if you want to delete folders and files inside directory then use

```
PATH = "dbfs/azure/directory/sub_dirctory"

for i in dbutils.fs.ls(PATH):
    dbutils.fs.rm(i[0],True)
```

Answer (score 1):

For python users you could do something like:

```
folder_path = 'adl://azurelake.azuredatalakestore.net/landing/stageone/'
path_list = [fileinfo.path for fileinfo in dbutils.fs.ls(folder_path)]
for path in path_list:
    dbutils.fs.rm(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`PATH = "adl://azurelake.azuredatalakestore.net/landing/stageone/"`

```py
for i in dbutils.fs.ls(PATH):
    dbutils.fs.rm(i[0])
```